# calculate the limit of averages series

Tags: calculus, limits

We were given those series in class:

$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n +b_n}2$

$b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_nb_n}$

when
$a_1, b_1$ are both positive

and we were asked to prove that this limits exist and equal:

$\lim_{x\to 0}a_n = \lim_{x\to 0}b_n $

I could prove they exist but not necessarily equal through this (for every n):

$a_n > a_{n+1} > b_{n+1} > b_n$

Can someone provide a **formal** proof

Comment: $a_1 , b_1 $ are both positive and real

Comment: See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean

Answer (score 1):

You already know that the limits exist, so let $\lim a_n = a$ and $\lim b_n = b$. They obviously satisfy $a = \frac{a+b}{2}$  (and $b=\sqrt{ab}$) which implies $2a = a+b$ which implies $a=b$.